# Переход к локальному репозиторию

Tags: git, git-remote

Я всегда пользовался интерфейсом гит. Возникла необходимость ввести команду через консоль. Дело в том, что при вводе команды `git remote -v` показывается не та папка, что мне нужна. Как я могу переключиться на другой локальный репозиторий?

Comment: на другой **локальный** репозиторий? просто перейдите в другой каталог. Или все таки удаленный репозиторий? В общем случае все просто

    git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here

Comment: После ввода этой команды, пытаюсь перейти на уже созданную в репозитории ветку git checkout [имя ветки]. Пишет что не может такую найти. Для перехода к локальному репозиторию выполнил следующую команду git remote set-url origin git: C:\DEV\main

Comment: @KrEnot, что конкретно вам надо осуществить и что не так в текущем выводе `remote -v`?

Comment: Есть 2 локальных репозитория. На данный момент консоль обращается к одному из них. Мне необходимо перейти на второй и работать с ним. Для перехода на нужный мне репозиторий выполнил команду, предложенную выше. После вывода remote -v возвращается следующее: 

    origin git: (fetch)
    origin git: (push)

До попытки перехода на нужный мне репозиторий в каждой строке печатался еще и адрес репозитория. Предположив, что я в нужном репозитории, пытаюсь перейти в уже созданную ветку. Но получаю ответ, что не может найти вводимую мной ветку. Что-то делаю неправильно, но не пойму что.

Comment: поставлю вопрос по другому - а зачем нужно перейти другой репозиторий? Он совершенно другой, чем Ваш текущий? или "очень похожий".

Comment: Ситуация такая. Сейчас консоль обращается к пустому репозиторию (т.е. внутри есть только папка git). И есть рабочий репозиторий, в котором находится проект, к которому я хочу перейти. Нет проблем склонировать проект заново с удаленного репозитория, но проблема в том, что консоль обращается все равно к пустому (Я подозреваю созданному автоматически при установке гит). В итоге мне просто нужно выполнить rebase, но никак не могу добраться до нужных мне веток. Я только начал работать с гит, и не совсем понимаю что я делаю не правильно.

Comment: Раз Ваша папка с репозиторием пустая, удалите папку и склонируйте проект по новой.

Comment: Удалил и склонировал. Теперь пишет следующее: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: Нет ли способа просто указать адрес локального репозитория и перейти к нему?

Comment: попробовал у себя склонировать локальный репозиторий. Все прошло без проблем. Что то делаете не так.

Comment: Видимо, вы не находитесь в папке с этим репозиторием. О какой именно консоли речь? Помогает ли `cd путь/к/репозиторию`?

Answer (score 1):

> пытаюсь перейти на уже созданную в репозитории ветку git checkout [имя ветки]. Пишет что не может такую найти.

Посмотрите, какие ветки у вас вообще есть. Поможет эта команда.

```
git branch --all
```

> Для перехода к локальному репозиторию выполнил следующую команду `git remote set-url origin git: C:\DEV\main`

Эта команда только устанавливает связь между репозиториями. Она не переносит содержимое. Чтобы перенести «оттуда — сюда»:

```
git pull origin branchname
```

«Отсюда — туда»:

```
git push -u origin branchname
```

> Нет ли способа просто указать адрес локального репозитория и перейти к нему?

Есть, но возможно, под «перейти» вы понимаете нечто другое. Нужно перейти в папку, в которой лежит репозиторий. Для этого используется команда `cd` (**c**hange **d**irectory).

```
$ cd ~/path/to/local/repository/one
$ git branch

(выводится список ветвей репозитория 1)

$ cd ~/path/to/another/local/repository/
$ git branch

(выводится список ветвей репозитория 2)
```